# Getting class not found when using opentelemetry-javaagent-1.31.0.jar with my app which post some data to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, open-telemetry-java

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:439)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:290)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:317)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:302)
at com.ericsson.bss.msg.client.api.impl.MsgProducer.(MsgProducer.java:80)
at com.ericsson.bss.msg.client.api.internal.impl.MsgProducerImpl.createProducer(MsgProducerImpl.java:357)
at com.ericsson.bss.msg.client.api.internal.impl.MsgProducerImpl.checkIfProducerInitialized(MsgProducerImpl.java:279)
at com.ericsson.bss.msg.client.api.internal.impl.MsgProducerImpl.sendMessage(MsgProducerImpl.java:291)
at com.ericsson.bss.msg.client.api.internal.impl.MsgProducerImpl.sendSync(MsgProducerImpl.java:124)
... 78 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter cannot be found
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:396)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:478)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:459)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:350)
... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiServletContextClassLoader.loadClass(OsgiServletContextClassLoader.java:128)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:417)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:406)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:394)
... 89 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter cannot be found by org.apache.aries.jax.rs.whiteboard_2.0.2
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiServletContextClassLoader.loadClass(OsgiServletContextClassLoader.java:121)
... 94 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter cannot be found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_8.0.15
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiServletContextClassLoader.loadClass(OsgiServletContextClassLoader.java:121)
... 94 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter cannot be found by org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jsp_8.0.15
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiServletContextClassLoader.loadClass(OsgiServletContextClassLoader.java:121)
... 94 more

I explored the ot-javaagent jar and all other jar https://opentelemetry.io/blog/2022/instrument-kafka-clients/  defined in this link but the class with package io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter is not found.

Comment: by disabling kafka metrics, add -Dotel.instrumentation.kafka.metric-reporter.enabled=false to jvm arguments    working